# Removing a dynamic Session Variable

Tags: php, session

I have a session variable with the following format:
`$_SESSION['user']['cart']['items']`
The items contains `[0][1][2]` so on and so forth depending on how many are in the cart. At the checkout we have a foreach loop through all of the items where it displays the item and cost based off the item id listed in each variable. EG

```
$items = $_SESSION['user']['cart']['items'];
foreach($items as $item) {
       return '<p>'.self::GetItemDetail($item, "name").' '.self::GetItemDetail($item, "cost").'</p>';
}
```

Now I take this and run it through my html page and Yay! We have all the items listed, but now say I want to add a Remove from cart button =O I'm at a loss. I can't unset the items variable, that would empty the entire cart. Since the variables are set dynamically when the item is added I don't know how I would go about making a remove button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It's suddenly hit me that I can use

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
//return the data
}
```

and the key SHOULD show up as the array value as something I can pass through a link

```
<a class='removeItem' data-link='".$key."'>Remove From Cart</a>
```

Then pass through the data-link attribute for my unset in the ajax call.
Not 100%, but going to try it out.

Comment: Just unset `$_SESSION['user']['cart']['items'][$i]`, where `$i` is the item they want to remove.

Comment: My issue with that is I have all my calls through another script, so say I have the checkout built with the above; I'm not sure how I would tell it to submit the ajax call to remove said variable, typically when I've dealt with variables they've always been set in stone, session->user->lang; session->user->id, I've never had a dynamic array listed inside of a variable, so I'm not sure how I would submit it. better wording would be I don't know how to make the call know I'm talking about `$i`

Comment: Your "suddenly hit me" is the proper way to do it.